# Resque like technology for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, resque

Resque is a Redis-backed Ruby library for creating background jobs, placing them on multiple queues, and processing them later.

https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque

Looks for something proven, and in use, if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks bryanmac, but ideally I'm looking for something a little less raw. Could be built on MSMQ thought.

Comment: http://scheduling.codeplex.com/
http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/01/lightweight-task-slash-job-scheduling-with-silverlight-support
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html

These are some I have found so far. Any others? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

It rocks.

Comment: I think is the most correct answer. and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DarcyThomas Thanks. From my years at this question, I think it is the only real answer. Hangfire rocks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Resque.
However if someone came to me with requirements like that, I would point them to [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com)

- It has bindings for many languages [including C#](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html) (as a WCF implementation).
- It offers (easy to configure): queues, pub/sub, routing, topic-routing (good for audit logs) etc.

  - See some examples here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
- Based on the AMPQ protocol/standard

If you are wanting to schedule background jobs (say a end of day, every hr etc., etc.) I would suggest looking at [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

So for a scalable, reliable, highly available etc, system I would use both. 
quartz.net for triggering regular jobs and rabbitmq for allocation and processing (retry etc) of both the scheduled tasks and for ad-hock task requests.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/alexdemers/csharp-resque

c# clone (raised an old wreck, but it now exists and may help someone

Answer (score -1):

Here is one I just turned up - Blue Collar

http://bluecollardotnet.org/

Comment: The blue collar site seems to be gone.